# Java regex split text (both the delimiter and the order may be unknown)

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to split a text like `"name:jack,berk,john;teacher:smith,jan;course:math;"` And I hope the result contains 3 sub-strings (or less, depends on the appearance of 'name' 'teacher' 'course'), which is:

- `"name:jack,berk,john;"`
- `"teacher:smith,jan;"`
- `"course:math;"`

But the appearance order of identifiers `'teacher,name,course'` is not fixed, it can be `'course ,name, teacher'` and it also can lack one or two, just like only has 'name' identifiers.

Also the delimiter between identifiers is not fixed, in the example is `';'`,but also can be `'、\\s,'`.

I have tried many times but it not works.

```
String str = "name:jack,berk,john;teacher:smith,jan;course:math;
str = str.replaceAll("(.*)(.)(name|teacher|course)(.*)(.)(name|teacher|course)(.*)", "$1--$3$4--$6$7");
System.out.println(str);
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of delimiter is `、\s,`??

Comment: between identifiers(name teacher course).

Comment: PS:I also want to konw which substring represents what identifier.(like substring1 is name,substring2 is teacher,substring3 is course)

Comment: There's technically no way to split a string if you have no idea what the delimiter is. Is `、\\s,` the only other possibility, or is it an example?

Comment: So essentially, the delimiters are the name, teacher & course words

Comment: @DanTemple That won't get you the values. What if the delimiter happend to be `ohn;`?

Comment: only 4 types of delimiter,which is 、;,  \\s （\\s means Blank Space）

Comment: @shmosel True, but the key words are the only consistent piece of information if the delimiters can change, so it's a good starting point. I'm thinking something like: 1) find the order of the key words 2) split on them 3) remove any of the possible delimiters from the ends of the values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** Regex without looking for a specific delimiter.

Rather than splitting the string do a match on this regex:

```
(name|teacher|course):(.+?)(?=\W*(?:name|teacher|course|$))
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lO3tL9)

**Code:**

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(name|teacher|course):(.+?)(?=\\W*(?:name|teacher|course|$))");
Matcher m = p.matcher(name:jack,berk,john;teacher:smith,jan;course:math;);
while (m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group(1) + " :: " + m.group[2]);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, the OP has stated that the delimiter could be anything, not just a semicolon (as in the example) So my point was that this answer seems to rely on the delimiter being a semicolon, doesn't it?

Comment: @anubhava I still have a question. When this regex be used in english it works good,but when I use chinese it doesnot work.             String str = "name:秦新锁;teacher:武山县给排水公司;course:韩天俊;";

Comment: Try using: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile(str, Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "name:jack,berk,john;teacher:smith,jan;course:math;";
    String[] values = str.split(";");

    for (String s : values) {
        if (s.contains("name:")) {
            System.out.println("name : " + s.replaceAll("name:", ""));
        } else if (s.contains("teacher:")) {
            System.out.println("teacher : " + s.replaceAll("teacher:", ""));
        } else if (s.contains("course:")) {
            System.out.println("course : " + s.replaceAll("course:", ""));
        }
    }
}
```

O/P :

```
name : jack,berk,john
teacher : smith,jan
course : math
```

Comment: This answer relies on the delimiter being a semicolon. `String[] values = str.split(";");` The OP stated that this cannot be relied upon `Also the delimiter between identifiers is not fixed, in the example is ';',but also can be '、\\s,'.`

Answer (score 0):

You can **replace all the delimiters with an unique delimiter** and then use `String.split`.

```
String input = "name:jack,berk,john;teacher:smith,jan-course:math;";
String uniqueDelimiter = ";";
String[] otherDelimiters = new String[2];
otherDelimiters[0] = "\\s";
otherDelimiters[1] = "-";
for (String delimiter : otherDelimiters) {
    input = input.replaceAll(delimiter, uniqueDelimiter);
}
String[] keyList = input.split(uniqueDelimiter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str.split("[、;,\\s](?=name|teacher|course|$)")
```